# Does valgrind crash all the time on Raspbian with an unhandled instruction?

Tags: raspbian

I've just run into a very strange issue with valgrind every time I'd like to profile my app on My RPi 3B with the current Raspbian: Valgrind complains about an *unhandled instruction* and exits, apparently before even starting to profile the program code itself. See this (rather long) output:

```cpp
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ valgrind ./autoradio
==22031== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22031== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22031== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22031== Command: ./autoradio
==22031==
/* several lines of output omitted */
==22031== Invalid read of size 8
==22031==    at 0x4844B8C: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==22031==  Address 0x5cf399c is 52 bytes inside a block of size 58 alloc'd
==22031==    at 0x48345E4: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:343)
==22031==    by 0x4DAB117: c4_String::c4_String(char, int) (string.cpp:120)
==22031==    by 0x4DAB413: operator+(c4_String const&, c4_String const&) (string.cpp:158)
==22031==    by 0x4DA00CB: c4_Field::Description(bool) const (mk4str.inl:214)
==22031==    by 0x4D9FEC7: c4_Field::DescribeSubFields(bool) const (field.cpp:108)
==22031==    by 0x4DA2E47: c4_HandlerSeq::Description() (handler.cpp:209)
==22031==    by 0x4DAA65F: c4_Storage::Description(char const*) (mk4.inl:139)
==22031==    by 0x4DAA6DB: c4_Storage::SetStructure(char const*) (store.cpp:320)
==22031==    by 0x4DAABC3: c4_Storage::GetAs(char const*) (store.cpp:307)
==22031==    by 0x9A833: database::database(std::string) (database.cpp:19)
==22031==    by 0x1E897: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (main.cpp:69)
==22031==    by 0x1E96F: _GLOBAL__sub_I_pigpiod_handler (main.cpp:1003)
==22031== 
disInstr(arm): unhandled instruction: 0xF1010200
                 cond=15(0xF) 27:20=16(0x10) 4:4=0 3:0=0(0x0)
==22031== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x48426f4.
==22031==    at 0x48426F4: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==22031== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==22031== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==22031== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==22031==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==22031==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==22031== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==22031==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==22031==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==22031== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==22031== probably kill your program.
==22031== 
==22031== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==22031==  Illegal opcode at address 0x48426F4
==22031==    at 0x48426F4: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
Opening database autoradio.db.==22031== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==22031==    at 0x53CF934: free_mem (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.19.so)
==22031==    by 0x53CF3C3: __libc_freeres (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.19.so)
==22031==    by 0x4023633: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:61)
==22031==    by 0x5198F13: std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.20)
==22031== 
==22031== 
==22031== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22031==     in use at exit: 15,347 bytes in 345 blocks
==22031==   total heap usage: 1,399 allocs, 1,054 frees, 37,292 bytes allocated
==22031== 
==22031== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22031==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22031==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22031==      possibly lost: 4,950 bytes in 163 blocks
==22031==    still reachable: 10,397 bytes in 182 blocks
==22031==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22031== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22031== 
==22031== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22031== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==22031== ERROR SUMMARY: 694380 errors from 201 contexts (suppressed: 3906 from 1)
```

This seems to be a known issue, which still persists: [Complaint in the RPI forum.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=166035) Obviously, this issue has not been solved yet. What can I do here?

Comment: `What can I do here?` Have you tried to contact the makers of valgrind as option 2 in the message suggests?

Comment: Pretty sure it does still do this although I have not checked in a while; I think there is no intention of fixing this.  However, [libasan](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) works and provides similar MM/access checks.  You don't have to install it from github, though, there is a distro package (`libasan5` -- so contra the github page it is working on ARM).

Comment: @Dirk: Several people have already done this. As the bug report https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=322935 states, the Valgrind developers don't regard this issue as a bug in Valgrind, yet see the use of the SETEND machine instruction (an ARM speciality BTW) in `libarmmem.so` as bad design. :( And @goldilocks: Thank you for the hint, but ASAN doesn't work for me either. See also my question at SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/1511071/how-can-addresssanitizer-throw-a-sigsegv-without-additional-info-every-time-id

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of `libarmmem.so` no longer have this problem.

The other error in the OP's question, the `Invalid read` is also at least half due to a problem in libarmmem.so. If you want to use Valgrind memcheck without lots of false positive errors coming from optimize str* and mem* functions you have a few choices.

1. Uninstall raspi-copies-and-fills. Which will also make your system slower.
2. Use the Valgrind suppression mechanism. Unfortunately that means that it will be difficult for Valgrind to detect genuine errors with uses of the optimized str* and mem* functions.
3. I've suggested a patch for libarmmem.so and I also have a fix ready for Valgrind (the Valgrind change won't work without the libarmmem.so patch). Details here https://bugs.launchpad.net/raspbian/+bug/2051392 . So you could get the source for libarmmemand Valgrind and then patch and build both.
4. Wait for libarmmem to get fixed and then wait for Raspberry Pi OS to get a version of Valgrind that works with libarmmem. That might take a long time.